# On MacPorts, Mavericks, and generated PDF files with latex/xelatex

Tags: macos, pdf, preview, macports, latex

So, I am using MacPorts and through MacPorts I want to use texlive in order to be able to build with latex/xelatex PDF documents.

Everything seems to be working fine, apart from the fact, that whenever I use a command of the form, say

```
open myFile.pdf
```

then in the terminal I get the error:

```
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

However, when I attempt to open in a similar manner pdf documents that I have created in the past, then these other documents are opened without any problems. So, my feeling is that this particular issue has something to do with the recent MacPorts versions of texlive and the dependancies that are there at the moment. On the other hand, I am not really sure if I can post something like this as a "bug" on MacPorts. So, what about you guys? Do you experience something similar?

Side notes:

1. Since I also wanted to use kile I have poppler installed with the
   extension +qt4+quartz.
2. Even if I open the pdf document on Preview (by first opening Preview and then the file using "File>Open ...") then I can not scroll through the document!
3. Using Okular and opening the dvi file, I can actually scroll the document.
4. Which brings us to the command that I use for translating the .dvi file to a .pdf file, which is "dvipdf", i.e.: dvipdf myFile.dvi

Any ideas on resolving this issue?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why don't you use http://tug.org/mactex/ ?

Comment: Because mactex has issues. Texlive is working. At least it was. Seriously though, mactex is *not* the way to go.

Comment: That kind of surprises me since MacTeX is built on top of TeXLive as far as I know… Anyway, If you could provide an example document it could be easier to help you, and don't forget there's http://tex.stackexchange.com too, so feel free to ask them too.

Comment: Asmus, thanks. Right now a simple tex document like this: 
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\title{Something}
\author{Someone}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\section{Hey}
Hi!
\end{document}
when it goes through latex and then dvipdf, then you can not scroll on Preview and neither can you open the pdf file from the command line. Really I am not asking for help about latex or xetex; not at all.

Comment: OK, I've created a document based on your structure, adding some lorem ipsum to get it to be longer than one page and it compiles fine using `latex input.tex && dvipdf input.dvi` (if I understood your compilation correctly). I can open the .pdf without issues. I'm running MacTex here, so I'm guessing your problem is due to poppler & kile? I'll try to install it and see if I can reproduce it..

Comment: No worries. The problem has been solved. I will post what I did soon. Thanks!